# Would this question fit on any SE site?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I'm currently improving my JavaScript/general math skills by writing functions to generate numbers, like the Fibonacci sequence, and I'm wondering if this would be useable anywhere in my Web Developer role. I want to find out if any other people have used any maths patterns, and if so where.

Whilst this question to me seems like it can have good answers, it seems a tad subjective an may get opinion based answers.

Is my assumption correct, that this question doesn't really fit anywhere in the SE model?

Comment: Are you asking in "general" for all SE sites or for SO only? In SO it's obviously off-topic, for other SE sites...who knows? They're too many!!! Try to post this meta question on meta.stackexchange.com!

Comment: Yeah I might try it there, I was thinking it **may** fit on either one of the maths sites, or maybe programmers. I'll leave this a bit (till after my dinner probably), then post it over on meta.se.

Comment: It won't be a good fit for Programmers.